# Can not read/write kafka stream as spark data frame stream on R

Tags: java, r, apache-spark, apache-kafka, sparklyr

I'm trying to read/write kafka stream as spark data stream. When I try below simple example from documentation of stream_read_kafka function

```
config <- spark_config()

# The following package is dependent to Spark version, for Spark 2.3.2:
config$sparklyr.shell.packages <- "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.1"

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", config = config)

read_options <- list(kafka.bootstrap.servers = "localhost:9092", subscribe = "topic1")
write_options <- list(kafka.bootstrap.servers = "localhost:9092", topic = "topic2")

stream <- stream_read_kafka(sc, options = read_options) %>%
  stream_write_kafka(options = write_options)

stream_stop(stream)
```

I'm getting below error

```
Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.subscribe(Ljava/util/Collection;)V
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.SubscribeStrategy.createConsumer(ConsumerStrategy.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReader.createConsumer(KafkaOffsetReader.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReader.<init>(KafkaOffsetReader.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.createContinuousReader(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.createContinuousReader(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:185)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sparklyr.Invoke.invoke(invoke.scala:147)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:123)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler.read(stream.scala:66)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:51)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:4)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:138)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I deployed kafka broker by using ambari 2.7.3 and Spark version I use is 2.3.1 and I also supplied below jars comes with hdp as sparklyr.jars.default config parameter. But still getting same error.

```
"/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/libs/kafka-clients-1.1.1.3.0.1.0-187.jar"
"/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/libs/kafka-streams-1.1.1.3.0.1.0-187.jar"
```

I also tried other spark-sql-kafka jars from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11/ but still didn't work.

Comment: instead of adding kafka-clients and kafka-streams in version 1.1.1, could you try adding kafka-clients 0.10.0.1? (I think kafka-streams is not required at all here)

Comment: @mike I tried but result is same